# Changing Skin/Color in CS:GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I play CS:GO, and usually I choose to play as the Terrorists. I don't actually know why it is, but the color of CTs clothing is a little dark and makes them to go hide easily.

My LED screen is not that good (I think the dark and bright points are low) and makes it difficult to look at it from the sides, so I sometimes don't see them while they are in dark places or when the backside of them is dark.

How can I change the color of them or at least change the skin of them? I myself didn't find a suitable skin.

Comment: I don't recommend you doing this at all, learn to play the game as it is. The game is supposed to have a level playing field, and you're trying to get an advantage. Use sound and the radar to figure out where enemy's are, and learn the map's camping spots. I would considering doing this a form of cheating. Unless your monitor is from the 1990, I can't see how it would make a difference.

Comment: @Sickest heh no its not from the 90s its a laptop that ive bought just 2 years ago. The screen is dark when I see it from bottom and it is too bright when I try to see it from top. I just wanted to lessen this hassle.

Comment: Changing the color of the skins of enemies is considered against the Terms & Conditions of the game.  You could theoretically do this in offline, as the server won't check your ingame files to see if they matchup, but Competitive and Casual servers that are protected by VAC will never let you play in it.

Comment: @howdareyou is right. While your asking to fix a hardware issue, the same practice could be used to make the enemie fluro-red, for example. Makes it a lot easier to pick off enemies at a distance, and gives you a very unfair playing advantage. If you are not playing while connected to the power adapter, I would recommend doing so. Laptop screens often go into low-power state when unplugged, which can have an adverse reaction in gaming.

Comment: You should just be able to bump up the contrast/brightness a) in-game and b) on the laptop Also: disable any brightness auto-adjustment on the laptop as well

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Ive finally found that this end is achievable by using a wall hack. I dont wanna use a wall hack so I decided to stay happy with what I have and what it is ...
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

The player skins depend on the map you are playing on. I don't know if you can influence this via workshop subscriptions for casual play, but for competitive play it is not possible.

Think about it, if you could freely choose a skin, what stops you to make bright red or green ones to get an advantage? Therefore everyone is forced to the same skins.

If your screen is too dark then look for gamma and brightness settings in the game, I am not sure they are available in the options menu though. If not, you might be able to play around with the corresponding console commands, for gamma that would be `mat_monitorgamma`, the dev wiki lists recommended values at about `2.2` for CRT monitors and `1.7` for LCD Screens.

Comment: In Casual mode it is possible to change the skins to everything you like.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he's talking about mod skins, where you download the skin and apply. Not the official skins.

Comment: Thanks but I dont think this can help ...

Answer (score 0):

For the competitive Game there is no way to change the Skins. The only thing you can change is in the Option menu. Things like Gamma and Brightness level.

To mess around with the original devault skins is a very bad idea.
If you change the skins in any way and start plaing online in a rated competitive Match then hope that VAC dose not notices that. VAC would ban you immediately and there is no return from a VAC ban.

So try first to change the skins (mods from steam workshop) and play on some random not rated Server to see if "skins" are realy the problem. A good start could be surf_ or zombie_ maps they mostly have changed skins.

Comment: Thanks for the info but I myself finally got that this is a form of cheating and it can be achieved using a wall hack (which does the same as what I want).

Comment: So you whant to have something like a Wall Hack ? or did i get your Comment wrong ?

Comment: No . I dont wanna use wall hack .

Comment: So then the answer is no you can not change your skins. Maybe you could upload a picture of your ingame problem. So people can tell you if its normal or not

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely could not play with the set colors, you could just play with color assist mode on.

Comment: I believe you are referring to a "colour blind" mode of some sort. Could you provide a little more information? Perhaps directions to it, from the options menu?